# first child in multiple sub containers

Tags: css, css-selectors

How am I abled to select the first, second and third *span* related to layer 1, independent from if it is the first child of a div at layer 2?

```
<div class="LAYER1">
  <div class="LAYER2">
    <span>FIRST<span>
  </div>
  <div class="LAYER2">
    <span>SECOND</span>
    <span>THIRD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

By using *span:first-child* I get FIRST and SECOND but I just want to get FIRST.

EDIT: I'm aiming for making a selection like "get me the first, second and third span children from LAYER1". SECOND and THIRD could be in the first LAYER2 div, too and the solution should not depend on that.

EDIT2: Example at http://jsfiddle.net/3hAEc/3/

Comment: So do you want to get the first, second and third spans, or only the first one?

Comment: all three are important, just provided an example for the first one how I tried and failed

Comment: You should be aware that the spans are not children of layer1, they are descendants. First is the first child of layer2, not of layer1

Answer (score 2):

Selecting only `<span>FIRST</span>` works like this (assuming the browser supports it)

```
.LAYER1 .LAYER2:first-child span { 
    // ...
}
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/3hAEc/

Comment: Comes very close but the problem is that SECOND and THIRD could be in the first LAYER2, too. Is there a way to make a selection like "get me the first, second and third span children from LAYER1"?

Comment: A solution to get all spans in order under `LAYER1` (cause `span:nth-of-type(1)` isn't working in that case) would require JavaScript.

Comment: Added an example to my post. Can anyone disagree with Sven? Hope so ;) But if you're right, I use JS.

Answer (score 0):

how about you add ids or classes to them, then select them that way ?

```
<div class="LAYER1">
  <div class="LAYER2">
    <span id="first_span">FIRST<span>
  </div>
  <div class="LAYER2">
    <span id="second_span">SECOND</span>
    <span id="third_span">THIRD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: sadly that is no option because they have to be selected dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.LAYER1 .LAYER2:first-child span:first-child /* first one*/
.LAYER1 .LAYER2+.LAYER2 span:first-child /* second one*/
.LAYER1 .LAYER2+.LAYER2 span:first-child+span /* third one*/
```

But this is only applicable for the current DOM.

Comment: I dont get why it selecting the first child on every `.LAYER2`

Comment: `.LAYER1 .LAYER2:first-child span` gets FIRST and SECOND, exactly not what I want to do, sorry

Comment: `X:first-child` seems to always select the first occurence of X as a child in every situation

Comment: @user1392185: Yes, that's intended behavior of `:first-child`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does work : http://jsfiddle.net/dmwfE/ . By the way, you forgot to close the first span, probly a typo

Comment: Just saw your edit, well as i said in my answer, that was working only on you current DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used the following JS solution by utilizing jQuery:

```
// for the first span, use 0 and increase for further children
$(".LAYER1").find("span").eq(0);
```

Comment: If it does what I think you intend to do, then as you may have suspected by now, it's not possible using pure CSS.